# (CAPL) how i assign array length by using parameter

Tags: vector, capl

```
void func(int a){
    byte arr[a];
}
```

this code is not working. how I assign array length by using parameter?

Comment: Declaring a variable of any kind inside a function is asking for troubles in CAPL from my experience. If you'd like a more positive feedback, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65488787/edit) your question to explain _why_ it is not working. Does it return error? Does it work in a way you don't mean for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

In CAPL you have many options to go, but first you'll have to consider you probably want to step back and ask yourself if you *really* need variable array size at runtime. The measurement performance is what you should be concerned about, declaring a suitable array size as design may be a safer approach.

A **global** array of parametric size could be something like this:

```
variables
{
    int arraySize = 256;
    byte arr[arraySize];
}
```

From the docs,

> Declaration of arrays (arrays, vectors, matrices) is permitted in CAPL. They are used and initialized in a manner analogous to C language.

In C, array size is constant:

> Array is a type consisting of a contiguously allocated nonempty sequence of objects with a particular element type. The number of those objects (the array size) never changes during the array lifetime. [[source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array)]

This is why your code is not working: you cannot create an array of runtime-based size. Similarly, from the same source

> **Variable-length arrays**
>
> If expression is not an integer constant
> expression, the declarator is for an array of variable size.
>
> Each time the flow of control passes over the declaration, expression
> is evaluated (and it must always evaluate to a value greater than
> zero), and the array is allocated (correspondingly, lifetime of a VLA
> ends when the declaration goes out of scope). The size of each VLA
> instance does not change during its lifetime, but on another pass over
> the same code, it may be allocated with a different size.

This is why you should be able to define a parametric array like I showed you. Even if in the code arraySize should change, `arr` will be of 256 elements for the execution of your CAPL script.

```
void func(int a){
    byte arr[a];
}
```

Will throw error, because `int a` is determined to be of non-constant time, thus violating the requirements above. What you can do, is to `memcpy` parts of a larger array to a location of choice, for example a smaller array, or employ a number of "buffer" arrays as you often see in CAPL scripts.

As I took it home, the gist of it is: use a larger size array, and be precise about where you are putting your information inside of it. Note that you *must* be precise, because every element in the array contains some kind of data, at init most of it is non-sense, and there is no safeguard for you against this digital noise.